# Charles proxy doesn't work with VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy

I'm stuck at setting Charles proxy to work throught VPN. It captures the traffic without VPN, but when I use VPN it doesn't capture anything.

The docs suggest to enable VPN first and then to launch Charles, and it worked for me a few times, but for some reason it stopped working now.

I use Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Vladislav i am facing same issue, how to resolve this issue. please help me.
I went through below link provided by cisco, but no useful.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/unified-communications/jabber/212044-Configure-Charles-Proxy-to-Capture-HTTPS.html

Comment: Hi @sham.y it worked for me with another VPN provider (another desktop app). With the previous provider I ended up not using a desktop app, but rather configuring Web proxy (domain, user name and password) directly in the Charles settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the other way around. Try running Charles first and then VPN.
https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/vpn-not-working-with-charles/

Comment: This doesn't work either. Charles doesn't see any packets going through VPN this way.